# How to create new instances of objects with custom SpecimenBuilder with AutoFixture

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit, autofixture

Currently I have such code:

```
private ConnectedClient WithConnection(IConnection connection)
{
    var builder = new ClientWithConnectionSpecimenBuilder(connection);

    Fixture.Customizations.Add(builder);
    var client = Fixture.Create<ConnectedClient>();
    Fixture.Customizations.Remove(builder);

    return client;
}
```

Basically I need to create new instances of `ConnectedClient` class in my tests code with specified connection. And I've built custom specimen builder to do it.

But there is no method like

```
Fixture.Create<T>(specimenBuilder)
```

so I need to customize the fixture.

"Fixture" there is the inherited protected property of my base tests class that is already set up with some custom AutoMoqData customization so I need to reuse it for creating objects.

Comment: I need to create multiple different objects with different specific connection, that's why I can't just use customization on the whole Fixture object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to use the one-off `Build` method to customize using a particular specimen builder:

```cs
var client = fixture.Build<ConnectedClient>().FromFactory(builder).Create();
```

Note that doing this will disable any other customizations from the fixture.

The DSL supports a bit more customization using `With` and `Without`, so if there's some additional customization you want to do on properties, you can do that:

```cs
var client = fixture.Build<ConnectedClient>()
    .FromFactory(builder)
    .With(cc => cc.SomeProperty, () => fixture.Build<T>().FromFactory(otherFactory).Create())
    .Create();
```

But that will get pretty tedious for significant customization. Autofixture is opinionated in this way.

The `Build` method is really intended as a one-off solution. If you want to rely more on the machinery of Autofixture to do everything *except* for creating the client connection, I would suggest relying on the existing `Freeze` method and `Frozen` attribute to keep the injected  `IConnection` the same for a given `ConnectedClient`, which would obviate the need for a specific `ISpecimenBuilder`.

Comment: What if I want multiple customizations? Can I chain FromFactory methods somehow?

Comment: How would you imagine multiple specimen builders would be used for a single type?
If it's not for a single type, can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: For example, with my current approach I can add customizations for different parameters of an object: imagine in my example there are several calls to Customizations.Add and I'm adding different customizations for different parameters that are passed into object's constructor (for example, Id that is 10 characters long and Connection parameter as specific object as in the example). Then, apart from specific connection, I would also have Id parameter set up.

Comment: So yes, specimen builders are for different types (or even for the same type but for different parameters of constructor of an object I'm building).

Comment: I updated the answer to expand on the build DSL. Your goals are rather opposing, regarding what autofixture supports. Up to you to decide which feels clearer/cleaner.

Comment: What if the object has no public properties and only private fields, and I'm customizing different parameters passed into constructor? Like in this article https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/19/Convention-basedCustomizationswithAutoFixture/

Comment: The `Build` DSL isn't compatible with providing multiple specimen builders for constructor parameters. You can still register a specimenbuilder for a particular constructor parameter, but you wouldn't be able to use both it and existing customizations as part of the `Build` DSL. The 'Freeze' attributes could help there, as would utilizing an ambient context that contains the correct connection.